# nodemailer router.post not posting

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, express, nodemailer

Hi I am trying to send an email from `contact.js` and front end `contact.jade`. Here is the code I am working on `contact.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
console.log('This block 1 is working');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('contact', {
        title: 'Contact'
    });
    console.log('This block 2 isworking');
});

router.post('/send', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('This block 3 isworking');
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'yyy@gmail.com',
            pass: 'xxx'
        }//console.log('This block 3 isworking');
    });

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'abc<abc@outlook.com>',
        to: 'yyy@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Website Submission',
        text: 'You have a new submission with the details ..Name ' + req.body.name
              + ' Email ' + req.body.email + ' Message ' + req.body.message.html
              + '<p>You got a new submission whth the following details</p><ul><li>Name: '
              + req.body.name + '</li><li>Email: ' + req.body.email + '</li><li>Message: '
              + req.body.message + '</li></ul>'
        // console.log('This block 4 isworking');
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('This block 5 isworking');
            console.log(error);
            res.redirect('/');
        } else {
            console.log('This block 6 isworking');
            console.log('message Sent: ' + info.response);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
        console.log('This block 7 isworking');
    });
    console.log('This block 8 isworking');
});
console.log('This block 9 isworking');
module.exports = router;
```

In this code I tested by loging which part block of code is working. The block 1 and block 9 is logging while loading contact in localhost. And on button click block 2 is  working i.e. router.get but router.post is not working as there is no log for block 3.
The gmail I am using I have already opened in browser after signing in.
Still I am not able to send the email.

[UPDATE] : this is the app.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var about = require('./routes/about');
var contact = require('./routes/contact');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/about', about);
app.use('/contact', contact);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});
module.exports = app;
```

[UPDATE]
 contact.jade
    extends layout

```
block content
.container
    form(method='post', action='contact/send')
        h1 Contact
        .form-group
            label Name
            input.form-control(type='text', name='name')
        .form-group
            label Email
            input.form-control(type='email', name='email')
        .form-group
            label Message
            textarea.form-control(name='message')
        button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') Submit
```

Every installation express nodemailer is also done.I am using `POST` on the client side contact/send don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: If _"block 3"_ isn't logged, I would suspect that the `POST /send` route isn't called. You're not showing the code that's supposed to call it.

Comment: I have defined the route for the contact in app.js and have an updated my post.

Comment: do you "Allow Less Secure Apps" in your gmail account https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: You should post the client-side code that will `POST` to `/send` (presumably in the `contact.jade` template).

Comment: Every installation express nodemailer is also done.I am using POST on the client side contact/send dont know where I am going wrong. Have tried with "Allow Less Secure Apps" but I have set a redirect to index page after sending mail and  I am not getting redirected to home page also.

Comment: I tried many possible solution. This error occurred after I installed mongodb. I unstalled node.js and reinstalled. Works good now. Thanks for your comments and effort. @robertklep